# How hot should water be to brew ground coffee directly in a cup?

Tags: ground-coffee, brewing-process

I don't have a coffee press so I just brew ground coffee as you would tea: in the cup.

How hot should be the water to brew with this method? Should it be boiling, or a lower temperature?

Answer (score 8):

Your method most closely resembles [Turkish Coffee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_coffee), which is suggested to be served at hot, **but not boiling** temperatures. Since the exposure to the grounds is so direct, it's easy to burn the coffee at boiling temperatures. You want a full body, but not a burnt taste (yuck!) [Turkish Coffee World](http://www.turkishcoffeeworld.com/How-to-make-Turkish-Coffee-s/54.htm) recommends about 158 degrees Fahrenheit or 70 degrees Celsius.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert, but a frequent enjoyer, and I also use freshly ground coffee in a cup, then pour water over it. **I always go with boiling water and have never heard of any reason to change.** My coffee tastes great too, so I think I'm doing it right.

By the way, in my country (Sweden) we call that a 'Turkish' brew.

Comment: How interesting! In Poland we use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I go with around 165 degrees Fahrenheight (73 C).

Comment: Why? Any references to back this up?